# Javascript works locally but breaks when running on server

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
/* The following code is executed once the DOM is loaded */

/* This flag will prevent multiple comment submits: */
var working = false;

/* Listening for the submit event of the form: */
$('#addCommentForm').submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    if(working) return false;

    working = true;
    $('#submit').val('Working..');
    $('span.error').remove();
    console.log('Test javascript 1')
    /* Sending the form fileds to submit.php: */

    $.post('comments/submit.php',$(this).serialize(),function(msg){
    console.log('Test javascript 2')
        working = false;
        $('#submit').val('Submit');

        if(msg.status){

            /* 
            /   If the insert was successful, add the comment
            /   below the last one on the page with a slideDown effect
            /*/

            $(msg.html).hide().insertBefore('#addCommentContainer').slideDown();
            $('#body').val('');
        }
        else {

            /*
            /   If there were errors, loop through the
            /   msg.errors object and display them on the page 
            /*/

            $.each(msg.errors,function(k,v){
                $('label[for='+k+']').append('<span class="error">'+v+'</span>');
            });
        }
    },'json');

});
```

});

This script works fine when I am running it locally however, when I uploaded it to the server it breaks when I click 'submit' and hangs on 'Working..'
The problem seems to come from the line

```
$.post('comments/submit.php',$(this).serialize(),function(msg){
```

I cant work out what the problem is. Can anyone help?

Comment: any errors in your console? Please add them to your question.

Comment: All that runs in the *client* irrespective of where it's served from. The likely problem is with `comments/submit.php` - have you looked in the browsers network inspector to verify the request/response to check its what you expect?

Comment: Found the problem! you were right, it was in the submit.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `comments/submit.php` parameter is not pointing to the correct location on your server. There is going to be some sort of ammending being done to the URL it is running from that is different in your local environment versus the production server.

Take a look at your Network tab in Chrome's Debug menu (or similar in another browser) to see where it's trying to go.

Most likely, the solution will be as easy as adding a `/` to the front of your post path, but there might be another step or two in the URL chain that you're missing.